# Can use this form in the informal conversation?

Tags: informal-language

Chatting with my club colleagues:

> If I get my winch driver qualification this weekend I can do winch on Friday.

Can I say:

> If I'm qualified this weekend, I can do Friday.

Comment: club colleagues? Winch driver? Hmm.

Comment: @Lambie https://youtu.be/Y4H47heaWXw

Comment: The confusing part to me is that if you only get your certification *this weekend*, how are you going to do it on Friday, which comes before this weekend?  Do you mean "next Friday"?

Comment: Just as I thought. You have to have at least a pilot private license, then a bunch of flying hours. "winch driver" does not exist: https://static1.squarespace.com/static/58641fb76a49630bc9b927c8/t/58bb54f144024365b326b480/1488671985858/Towing+glider+experience+requirements.pdf Being a tow pilot, requires a specific rating.

Comment: @Lambie winch driver operates the winch itself. To operate the winch you need to be cleared by the club authorized person :). Winch driver is on one side of the cable, the glider pilot is on the other side :)

Comment: @Lambie the guy sitting in this machine is a winch driver https://youtu.be/dVMUbbwti24 Club members drive the winch voluntarily helping colleagues getting into the air

Comment: @stangdon: It works if today's the Friday before :)

Comment: When you pose questions, provide decent context. Otherwise, it becomes a big mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your colleagues know you're talking about winching, yes, you can say that.

If the test happens this weekend it might be clearer to say, "**If I qualify** this weekend I can do Friday."

If you have taken the test and are simply waiting to hear the result, then "**If I receive my qualification** this weekend I can do Friday" would be more accurate.

Comment: It turns out it ain't driving or winching. It's towing a glider and you have to be a pilot. There is no license for winching.